# Get current request in Custom Spring Scope

Tags: java, spring, jsf, servlets, request

i write a custom spring scope base on FacesContext Logique,

```
public class DynamicScope implements Scope{
    @Override
    public Object get(String name, ObjectFactory<?> objectFactory) {
        AbsErpFolder erpFolder = null;
        if (FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()!=null)            
            erpFolder = (AbsErpFolder)FacesUtils.getExternalContext().
getRequestMap().get( ErpFolderKey );
    ............
}
```

Now i need to instanciate a bean in FileServlet Filter using

```
WebApplicationContext wsc = WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(config.getServletContext());
IGenericService erpFileService = (IGenericService) wsc.getBean("erpFileService");
```

The problem is during the execution my ServletFile the current FacesContext is null (the dynamic scope can't work ) so how to get the current request ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ThreadLocal should do the trick
 ( Defined in my first Filter )

```
public static ThreadLocal servletRequestHolder  = new ThreadLocal();
public static HttpServletRequest getCurrentRequest(){
    return (HttpServletRequest) servletRequestHolder.get();
}
@Override
protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
   servletRequestHolder.set( request );
...........
}
```